# Can't understand this line of code

Tags: php, ajax

```
  // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
   if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
     $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
      if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
          if ($hint === "") {
            $hint = $name;
          } else {
            $hint .= ", $name";
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

The full thing is located at: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp?

I don't really understand the part from the foreach and under but everything else including the ajax is understandable.  Can someone explain mainly the

```
      if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
```

This is the only real roblem, I don't get.  What exactly is this line doing :) Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF block is executed if $q contains string $name length between 0 to length of $q.
For example if $q = "hello world" and $name = "hello" then IF is executed.
if $q = "hello world" and $name = "world" then If is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

$len variable come's from your request length.

If you'r request is Hege len will be 4;

$name is one of them array value.

substr function getting array element with query lenght.

For example in our case our query length is 4. Second array element is Brittany from substr function we will get only brit stristr function will check Hege and Brti is equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

here code start with

foreach($a as $name)

--> which will loop all names stored in $a array as $name.

--> and then substr($name, 0, $len).

where $len is the length of your query string parameter.

so, finally substr($name, 0, $len) return only that portion of string from stored name array starting from 0 to your query string length.

and after that stristr function.

which will find the first occurrence of your query string inside the returned portion of string from your stored name arrays with substr function and finally  return the rest of the string.

so, at last $hint is initially blank variable. So at the end of the loop if only one match found then it only display single name and if more than one match found then it will display name with comma seprated.